# Which design pattern to use for my scenario?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

During runtime, TableA, or TableB or TableC may created.

```
public class TableA  {
    public void methodA()  {
        doSomethingA();
    }

    public void methodB() {
        doSomethingB();
    }
}

public class TableB extends TableA  {
    @Override
    public void methodA()  {            
    }

    protected void methodC()  {
    }
}

public class TableC  extends TableA {
    @Override
    public void methodB()  {            
    }

    public void methodD()  {
    }
}
```

I have another table called TableX.

```
public class TableX  extends TableA {

    public void methodX()  {       
    }

    public void methodY()  {
    }
}
```

Now I want TableX functionality- methodX(), methodY()  apply to TableB, TableC

I cant take out methodX(), methodY() and put into TableA as these are TableX specific module features.

So now during runtime TableA, TableB, TableC, TableX(TableA), TableX(TableB), TableX(TableC) may created. Any design pattern I can apply, so that no matter what Table created, as long as it extends from TableA, TableX also can support it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about adding functionality on top `TableA` objects. [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern maybe what you are looking for.

```
class TableX extends TableA {
    private TableA innerObject;
    public TableX(TableA inner) { innerObject = inner; }

    public methodA() {
        innerObject.methodA(); 
        ....
    }

    ...
}

TableB bObject = new TableB();
TableX decoratedBObject = new TableX(bObject);
decoratedBObject.methodA();
```

Comment: In this case, is there a difference between Decorator and Adapter? I don't seem to get the difference, though I feel that the intentions of the two patterns are different...

Comment: You are right, there is a fine line. The reason I think limckmy is looking for `Decorator` is this line `public class TableX  extends TableA {` So he/she is looking to wrap the object and keep the same interface. In case of an Adapter you would provide a new interface to the wrapped object.

Comment: Nice catch Sameer! I was sure Adaptor was the answer as well, until you pointed this out.

Comment: @Sameer:I have a clarification .Consider a list of TableA objects.List<TableA>. I add bObject and decoratedObject to that list and pass it on to some method(name it Processor) for processsing. In Processor method, i need to call methodX() only on decorated objects in the list, else i should call methodA. How do i do that?

Comment: you can only call methods of TableA on such objects. What you can do is to have some method in TableA. Let there be a default implementation which may do nothing. You override the method in TableX, and call methodX. It is a bit difficult to make suggestions without knowing what these classes and methods are meant to do, however.

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time figuring out what you mean, but I think what you want is a [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), also known as Wrapper.